# How to pass the parameter with pop in wix react-native-navigation?

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

how to pass parameters in pop method.

Requirement: There are two screens, screen 1 has two tabs like this: Address and Billing. There are two button on each tab layout. On click button go to screen 2 after functionality back to screen 1 but now which tab is active. If go to address tab so back to address tab same as billing tab.

Tell me how to do it?

Comment: How you implement the tab feature . Did you use any package like "react-native-tab-view" for it ?

Comment: yes I have used this package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass callback while pushing screen like

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: "Your.ScreenName",
    options: {
      callback:this.yourCallBackFun
    }
  }
});
```

Now while pop you can call that function like

```
this.props.callback();
Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId);
```

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Screen A:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {func: this.func});
...
func = value => {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Screen B:

```
this.props.navigation.getParam('func')();
```

You can call ScreenA function like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Screen1:**

Write your navigation function and callback function in your first screen.
Pass callback function as a navigation parameter white pushing the screen.

```
const cbFunction = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve();
});

const navigation = () => {
  const { componentId } = this.props;
  Navigation.push(componentId, {
    component: {
      name: `SCREEN_NAME`,
      options: {
        cbFunction: this.cbFunction
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Screen2:**

Write a function to go back to first screen. And call callback function from navigation parameter.

```
const goBack = async () => {
  const { cbFunction, componentId } = this.props;
  await cbFunction();
  Navigation.pop(componentId);
}
```